# HttpClient.get No overload match this call

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to be able to download a file (here using a blob). For this purpose I need to retrieve the filename from the server which is embedded in the header "content-disposition".
Here my function :

```
const header = {Authorization: 'Bearer  ' + token};
const config = {headers: header, responseType: 'blob' as 'blob', observe: 'response' as 'response'};
return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Blob>>(url, config);
```

But I got the error :

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: { Authorization: string; }; responseType: "blob"; observe: "response"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
```

When I go to the function definition, I get :

```
/**
 * Constructs a `GET` request that interprets the body as a `Blob` and
 * returns the full `HTTPResponse`.
 *
 * @param url     The endpoint URL.
 * @param options The HTTP options to send with the request.
 *
 * @return An `Observable` of the `HTTPResponse` for the request,
 *  with the response body as a `Blob`.
 */
get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe: 'response';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'blob';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>;
```

I don't see what's I'm doing wrong. Can you help me please ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try `return this.http.get('url', config);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a generic version of the function, but looking at the non-generic docs. There is no generic overload that accepts `observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'`.

Instead, use the non-generic version:

```js
const header = {Authorization: 'Bearer  ' + token};
const config = {headers: header, responseType: 'blob' as 'blob', observe: 'response' as 'response'};
return this.http.get(url, config);
```

All of the generic overloads only allow `responseType: 'json'`.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts